# Upload jar file with Play Framework based on an ajax request

Tags: ajax, file-upload, playframework, multipartform-data, executable-jar

I am trying to upload an executable jar file with a Play application. Even if the file is indeed transfered, it gets corrupted during the transfer. I mean that I cannot execute it anymore. Besides, if I look on the properties of the file, the one transfered is slightly smaller than the other, just from a few octets. I have used the same to code to upload txt files, and it worked perfectly. Therefore I guess that this has to do with the content type or the encoding, or someting like that...

Could you help me with this?
Thank you very much :)

Server code:

```
    @Security.Authenticated(Login.CheckLogin.class)
    public static Result uploadJarFile() {
       Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
       Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart jarFile = body.getFile("jarFile");
       if (jarFile != null) {
           String jarPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + jarFile.getFilename();
           File file = jarFile.getFile();
           File destination = FileUtils.buildEmptyFile(jarPath);
           FileUtils.copyFile(file, destination);
           return ok();
       } else {
           System.err.println("Error while uploading jarFile !!");
           return redirect(routes.Application.main());
       }
   }
```

Client code:

```
function uploadJar(){
    var formData = new FormData($("#loadJarForm")[0]);
    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.uploadJarFile()
            .ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("ok");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            }
    );
}   

            <form name="loadJarForm" id="loadJarForm" action="javascript:;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div>
                    <input type="file" name="jarFile" id="jarFile">
                </div>                    
                <button type="submit" id="jarUpload" onclick="uploadJar();">Upload</button>
            </form>
```